# tmux status bar keeps echoing on gnome terminal

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal, signal

I'm unable to find the search terms for this problem, so I've attached a screenshot. Every minute, the tmux status bar outputs a new status line instead of updating. This seems to happen mainly on gnome terminal.

[image: tmux-status-bar]

What might be the problem?

Comment: could someone migrate this question to unix & linux?